# Plot values to grid (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh

I have X and Y data points (locations) I have generated to simulate a spiral trajectory. I also have raw data that I would like to plot at these points.

The data points X and Y, as well as the raw data are 4x500 matrices.

I would like to plot the raw data at the locations specified by X and Y.

I have tried using functions such as plot3, mesh, and surf; however none of them plot the data without having the points connected.

In MRI lingo, I am trying to plot raw spiral k-space (I simply want to plot it).

I feel like like there is a very simple answer here. Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

My failed attempts (which all somewhat fail the same way):

```
1. surf(X,Y,log(Kspace),'EdgeColor','None','facecolor','interp'), view(2)
2. pcolor(X,Y,log(Kspace))
3. mesh(X,Y,log(Kspace))
```

Here is an example of what I would like to see. In terms of code, there's not much there (other than the generation of the spiral trajectory, which I cannot share). I am just looking for a proof of concept way to achieve my goal.

[image: Spiral K-space]

Comment: Please post a minimal example with data and explain the exact type of plot you'd like. Is the raw data a _z_ that depends on _x_, _y_? In that case, to avoid the points being connected you can use something `plot3(x,y,z,'.')` (or change the marker)

Comment: Using plot3(x,y,z,'.') destroys the information from z, such that when I view as a 2D image, every point has a different color that does not correspond to the z values.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see what you want. In your example image I assume the x and y positions of the dots are given by x and y vectors. And the gray level is determined by some other vector say z?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like! It sounds very simple, so I think I am either over thinking it, or using the wrong function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`scatter`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html):

```
x = (30-(0:.01:20)).*sin((0:.01:20)*pi); % Just some example x data
y = (30-(0:.01:20)).*cos((0:.01:20)*pi); % Just some example x data
z = 1:numel(x); % Just some example z (color) data
scatter(x,y,20,z,'.'); % 20 is marker size. Adjust manually
set(gca,'color','black') % black background
colormap parula % choose colormap
axis equal % set equal scale on both axes
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Shinobii Great! Glad I could help